# Remove Text from Image (Comic) without using OpenCV

Tags: python, image-processing, google-cloud-vision

I am working on a project to translate comics completely. One of the steps requires me to remove all of the text from the image. I have tried using OpenCV's inpainting method, but it's not giving me a good result.

Note: The background can be dynamic, ranging from solid colors to designs. That's why I went with inpainting.

What can I do to fix this? If not, a new approach will also work.

My current approach:

Using the word level bounding boxes from Google Cloud Vision, I inpaint each of them using OpenCV's inpaint method

```
def remove_text(imagePath, bounds):
  img = cv2.imread(imagePath)
  mask = np.zeros(img.shape[:2],dtype="uint8")
  for box in bounds:
    points=np.array(box)
    cv2.fillPoly(mask, np.int32([points]),(255,255,255))
    img = cv2.inpaint(img,mask,1,cv2.INPAINT_TELEA)
  return img
```

Original Image:

[image: Original Image]

Text Removed:

[image: Removed Text Image]

Comment: look at the word boundaries. they're too tight. widen them by a pixel. -- [mre] should come with data to reproduce the problem, i.e. the word boxes for the image you present. -- since translation involves a lot of manual work anyway, you might as well erase all that text manually (with a drawing tablet?). OpenCV's old inpainting methods are decades old. they amount to blurring, drawing colors from the edges into the hole.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I tried padding the boundaries of the boxes. But I got worse results since it started taking into account the nearby words. What inpainting methods would you recommend?

Comment: you aren't supposed to inpaint each box individually, but all of them together. then "nearby words" won't affect the result. you may still have to deal with _other_ stuff in the picture (aside from the white bubble background) unduly getting drawn into the holes. -- what I would recommend? that you [edit] your question to add the word box coordinate data, so people can reproduce the problem. so far, you're asking for dry hypothesizing. you should also present a page that's "harder". you said you don't just deal with white-background bubbles...